# Know previous page in Winter '18

Tags: apex, visualforce, winter18

I was using document.referrer to know the previous page but right now in winter '18 document.referrer has only the host

Previous winter '18
document.referrer // "https://prefix.na50.visual.force.com/myPreviousPage"

Winter'18
document.referrer // "https://prefix.na50.visual.force.com/"

Somebody knows how I can obtain the previous page in a visualforce page?

Comment: Is the previous page also a Visualforce page?

Comment: Yes it's a visualforce page

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Salesforce improves the browser security ([release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_security_browser_security.htm)) and that is the reason because the referrer is only returning the host. However it's possible disabled this feature in the org in Setup -> Session Settings -> Referrer URL protection

[image]

Comment: Nice find! Thanks for sharing! Don't forget to come back in two days and accept this answer. :)

Comment: I love it when Salesforce add security features that break my managed packages.